# Connection is slow while using jdbc 8.4.1

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, windows-authentication, jtds

We have an application where we previously used JTDS-1.2.2 jar for connecting to the SQL server using windows authentication and we use NTLMv2 in our environment.

Now we are using mssql jdbc-8.4.1 to connect to the SQL server using windows authentication, but now, for creating 30 connections it takes almost 15 minutes.

Previously while using JTDS-1.2.2, it would take just few milliseconds for creating the 30 connections.

Tried using the same jdbc jar using SQL authentication, the connection is very fast (less than 1 second).

No changes done in the network recently.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try a somewhat later version of the driver? I think 12 is out now. It's usually slow to open a first Windows Auth connection but if you don't close your jvm and create new connections, it takes no time at all

Comment: Are you forcing it to use NTLM?  It could be trying and failing to use Kerberos first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-ntlm-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @siggemannen - I ll try that and update.

Comment: @fayaz did you make any progress on this? I'm seeing the same but with driver version 12.2. I'm forcing NTLM.

Comment: @Steve - No progress. Btw, forcing NTLM means, NTLM v2?

Comment: @Fayaz I mean setting the parameters authenticationScheme=NTLM and integratedSecurity=true

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - Yes we are forcing NTLM, how can we resolve this?